# Spark DataSource V2 API

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-connector

I have been trying to create a Custom Spark Data source using V2 API.

As per [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15689), it is in master and available for use. But when tried to use it in my project, compilation failed citing that no such package path exists in v3.3.1.

```scala
package closed.source.gs

import org.apache.spark.sql.sources.v2.DataSourceV2
class DefaultSource extends DataSourceV2{

}
```

Error:

```
...../gs/DefaultSource.scala:3:37:: object v2 is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql.sources
[error] import org.apache.spark.sql.sources.v2.DataSourceV2
```

Any ideas on what happened to V2 APIs? Did spark devs refactor this?
Are there any good latest articles that can help me here?

Already read but unhelpful links:
https://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/spark-datasource-v2-part-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data source API v2, introduced in Spark 2.3, has been heavily refactored in Spark 3. Here's [API improvement proposal document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DDXCTCrup4bKWByTalkXWgavcPdvur8a4eEu8x1BzPM/edit) if you'd like to learn more about motivation behind it.

So in Spark 2 you were extending `DataSourceV2` interface, but don't look for it - it no longer exists. Instead you create a set of classes in a dedicated package.

Here's a [blog post series](https://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/categories/datasource-v2-spark-three/) about implementing a custom data source in Spark 3. It's worth reading through, but if you want jump straight to [part 3](https://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/spark-datasource-v2-part-3) for a concrete example with [code](https://github.com/phatak-dev/spark-3.0-examples/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/madhukaraphatak/spark/sources/datasourcev2/SimpleDataSource.scala).